# Eclipse PYDEV: How to set up PYTHONPATH so that pip package in development is seen as a module

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

I am working on a pip package.  I install it for dev with 'pip install -e .'
When I try to run one of the scripts I get 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotnetcdf.plot_diffs'; 'plotnetcdf' is not a package' I've tried a number of configurations of the PYTHONPATH in "Properties" for this project(with or without source folder specified) to no avail. Even if I unistall the pip dev package I still have the same issue.
This is a recurring problem with all such projects. What is the correct way to set this up?
Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0) with PyDev for Eclipse 9.3.0.202203051235

Comment: Can you try using LiClipse instead ( it’s a light weight eclipse that comes preinstalled with PyDev ). Also can you please post a screenshot of your project structure

Comment: No, I've never tried it. OTOH it seems that I have gotten it to work, meaning that I can run the scripts fine from Eclipse, however all imports are marked as an error in all the files. Annoying but not a show stopper